# Is it possible to generate a Soundwave QR Code like in Spotify using JS or JS libraries?

Tags: javascript, qr-code, spotify

Is it possible to Generate a **Sound Wave QR CODE** like in Spotify using only Javascript? or any front-end libraries?

I've noticed in Spotify they have a **Sound Wave QR CODE** to redirect you to a playlist or songs, but they need you to use their **camera** on the Spotify app (located at their search box, right-side the camera icon) for it to work, If you are using any camera application except theirs it will not work.

I'm thinking of generating a **Sound Wave QR CODE** based on any **.mp3**, **.wav**, **.wma** that is scannable by the default camera app, tried to look for a library that will help me with this but unfortunately I cannot find any. I found these two https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/QRCodes, https://github.com/zxing/zxing/ though I think it won't help me.

So I'm starting to think that this might be impossible using only javascript or any front-end libraries... If there's one could you point it out to me? or this type of feature/tech is really impossible

Comment: I really like this question and have tried to do similar things in the past. Have you seen this article explaining [Spotify's QR code](https://boonepeter.github.io/posts/2020-11-10-spotify-codes/) design?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan awesome this https://boonepeter.github.io/posts/2020-11-10-spotify-codes/ article helps, thanks! If the regular QR Code counts, then yes, I used this lib https://github.com/neocotic/qrious to generate QR Codes, but similar to sound wave QR? I've not started anything yet, Spotify sound wave qr works only if you use their camera scanner, it doesn't work on default camera app, seems like they have modified something to the cam to specifically read and scan their own sound wave QR codes, if the default camera app can't scan it, then I think this might be not possible at the moment